# Error when passing parameter from url to method

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am using Flask for my webservice and when I try to access the following url

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/2,3/5,6
```

I receive the following error:

```
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: getDistance() got an unexpected keyword argument 'startCoord'
```

How can I fix this error?

**Code**:

```
@app.route("/<string:startCoord>/<string:endCoord>",methods=['GET'] )
def getDistance():
startLat, startLng = startCoord.split(',')
end1Lat, endLng = endCoord.split(',')

print("/api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car?api_key=" + config['EndPoint']['api_key'] + "&start=" + startLat + "," + startLng + "&end=" + end1Lat + "," + endLng)
```

**Output**:

```
['API_KEY']
<Section: API_KEY>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are meant to define your route like this:

```
@app.route("/<string:startCoord>/<string:endCoord>",methods=['GET'] )
def getDistance(startCoord, endCoord):
    startLat, startLng = startCoord.split(',')
    end1Lat, endLng = endCoord.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

url encoded arguments should be in the function arguments :

```
@app.route("/<string:startCoord>/<string:endCoord>",methods=['GET'] )
def getDistance(startCoord,endCoord):
```

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules